# QT EXE Failed to execute

Tags: qt, qml, windeployqt

I am developing a windows application with qml qt. My qml application is linked with different external libraries and one of them is VLC. I generated the dependencies using generated myApp.exe file from release folder with the following command:

***windeployqt.exe --qmldir [myqmlFilesPath] [pathTo myApp.exe]***

I checked all the dependencies using dependency walker and it work fine for my system. But when I tried to run this on another system it give the error of missing libvlccore.dll. I added it manually but with this the application failed to run on my own system. The screenshots are attached with this. I searched alot on google but nothing helped. Thanks
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElCaz.png)

Comment: What does dependency walker say now? If you are seeing that dialog, it is likely to report something different now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windeployqt **does not** deploy non-Qt libraries, you have to explicitly copy all non-Qt third-party libs  you are using yourself

Comment: Thanks for your response. Explicitly copping crash the exe in my system.